# Desabilitar Inputs baseado em evento Click de RadioButton

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia pessoal! Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para criação de provas, e estou criando uma tela para editar as questões criadas e que já estão salvas no banco de dados. Ao selecionar a questão existem dois radio buttons que buscam no banco de dados o tipo da questão (Dissertativa ou Objetiva) de acordo com o tipo já cadastrado na tela de criação da questão. Ou seja ele busca o valor no banco e marca o radio button conforme o tipo da questão. Se a questão é Objetiva o sistema habilita o campo enunciado e as alternativas de A a E. E se for Dissertativa ele desabilita as alternativas e habilita o enunciado. O que está acontecendo é que se a questão é Dissertativa o sistema busca os dados e desabilita as alternativas e se eu tento mudar o radio button para Objetiva ele não habilita os campos mais das alternativas. Segue estrutura do código:

```
<form method="POST"><br>
        <span class="login100-form-title p-70">Editar Questão Cadastrada</span><br>
            <center>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo" id="rbDissertativa" value="D" required <?php echo ($tipo == 'D') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> onclick="disableAlternativas()"> 
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="dissertativa">Dissertativa</label>
               </div>

               <div class="form-check">
                   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo" id="rbObjetiva" value="O" required <?php echo ($tipo == 'O') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> onclick="enableAlternativas()">  
                   <label class="form-check-label" for="objetiva" >Objetiva</label>
               </div>

                <label for="enunciado">Enunciado: </label>
                <input type="text" id="enunciado" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="enunciado" size="500" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enunciado" value="<?php echo $enunciado; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?>><br><br>
       
                <label for="a">A) </label>
                <input type="text" id="resposta_A" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_A" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa A" value="<?php echo $resposta_A; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?> disabled><br><br>

                <label for="b">B) </label>
                <input type="text" id="resposta_B" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_B" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa B" value="<?php echo $resposta_B; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?> disabled><br><br>

                <label for="c">C) </label>
                <input type="text" id="resposta_C" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_C" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa C" value="<?php echo $resposta_C; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?> disabled><br><br>

                <label for="d">D) </label>
                <input type="text" id="resposta_D" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_D" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa D" value="<?php echo $resposta_D; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?> disabled><br><br>

                <label for="e">E) </label>
                <input type="text" id="resposta_E" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_E" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa E" value="<?php echo $resposta_E; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?> disabled><br><br>

                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idquestao" value="<?php echo $idquestao; ?>">
                    <a href="questao.php" class="btn btn-dark">Cancelar</a>
                    <input type="submit" tabindex="1" class="btn btn-dark" name="acao" value="<?php echo $descr_acao; ?>" <?php echo $podeAlterar; ?> >
                </div>
            </center>
    </form>
```

Código da função para desativar e ativar as alternativas:

```
<script>
    function disableAlternativas() {
        document.getElementById('enunciado').disabled=false
        document.getElementById('resposta_A').disabled=true
        document.getElementById('resposta_B').disabled=true
        document.getElementById('resposta_C').disabled=true
        document.getElementById('resposta_D').disabled=true
        document.getElementById('resposta_E').disabled=true 
    }

    function enableAlternativas() {
        document.getElementById('enunciado').disabled=false
        document.getElementById('resposta_A').disabled=false
        document.getElementById('resposta_B').disabled=false
        document.getElementById('resposta_C').disabled=false
        document.getElementById('resposta_E').disabled=false
        document.getElementById('resposta_D').disabled=false
    }
</script>
```

O código completo da página está disponível [aqui](https://github.com/MAUPEARS/editar_prova/blob/master/page_1).
Se alguém puder me dar uma força <3

Comment: Não tem como simular esse erro, até onde você postou, o código não está errado. Mas e quanto ao restante do seu HTML? Esses elementos com id `enunciado`, `resposta_A`, `resposta_B`... existem mesmo? Não está ocorrendo duplicação de ids na sua página? O console do seu navegador apresenta algum erro?

Comment: Bom dia. quando alterno de radio button o sistema deveria alternar entre quais campos vão estar habilitados ou não, ele não mostra erro no console, acredito que só não esteja executando a função que desabilita e habilita os campos da tela. Segue código completo:

Comment: https://github.com/MAUPEARS/editar_prova/blob/master/page_1

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no [código que você disponibilizou no GitHub](https://github.com/MAUPEARS/editar_prova/blob/master/page_1), removi os trechos de PHP pois estes não são replicáveis para o exemplo, o trecho html para o Form ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
    <span class="login100-form-title p-70">Editar Questão Cadastrada</span><br>
        <center>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo" id="rbDissertativa" value="D" required onClick="disableAlternativas()"> 
                <label class="form-check-label" for="dissertativa">Dissertativa</label>
           </div>

           <div class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo" id="rbObjetiva" value="O" required onClick="enableAlternativas()" >  
               <label class="form-check-label" for="objetiva" >Objetiva</label>
           </div>

            <label for="enunciado">Enunciado: </label>
            <input type="text" id="enunciado" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="enunciado" size="500" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enunciado" ><br><br>
   
            <label for="a">A) </label>
            <input type="text" id="resposta_A" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_A" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa A"><br><br>

            <label for="b">B) </label>
            <input type="text" id="resposta_B" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_B" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa B" /> <br><br>

            <label for="c">C) </label>
            <input type="text" id="resposta_C" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_C" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa C" ><br><br>

            <label for="d">D) </label>
            <input type="text" id="resposta_D" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_D" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa D"><br><br>

            <label for="e">E) </label>
            <input type="text" id="resposta_E" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" name="resposta_E" size="200" maxlength="200" placeholder="Alternativa E"> <br>

            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="idquestao" >
                <a href="questao.php" class="btn btn-dark">Cancelar</a>
                <input type="submit" tabindex="1" class="btn btn-dark" name="acao" >
            </div>
        </center>
```

Já o script seria:

```
        function disableAlternativas() {
            document.getElementById('enunciado').disabled=false;
            document.getElementById('resposta_A').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('resposta_B').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('resposta_C').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('resposta_D').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('resposta_E').disabled=true ;
        }

        function enableAlternativas() {
            document.getElementById('enunciado').disabled=false
            document.getElementById('resposta_A').disabled=false
            document.getElementById('resposta_B').disabled=false
            document.getElementById('resposta_C').disabled=false
            document.getElementById('resposta_E').disabled=false
            document.getElementById('resposta_D').disabled=false
        }
```

Você pode testar a funcionalidade do código [no JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz7tfx9k/).